# I am on Ventura - I don't see this torrc file at all

Tags: configuration, error, startup

My tor is installed in the applications keep getting this error that my torrc file could be corrupted. I have deleted and re-installed.

my Library/app support/ does not have a Tor anything directory?

any ideas where this torrc file lives? did a search, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The path to torrc is /Users/your_directory/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/torrc
Obviously, you have to replace "your directory" by the name of the user account on which you installed Tor.